# Symfony form Collection rendering is of hidden type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I tried to render Symfony 5 collectiontype, but when I render it is blank and the source says it is of Hidden type.
I used exact code from [Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html):

```
    <ul id="email-fields-list"
    data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.emails.vars.prototype)|e }}"
    data-widget-tags="{{ '<li></li>'|e }}"
    data-widget-counter="{{ form.emails|length }}">
    {% for emailField in form.emails %}
      <li>
          {{ form_errors(emailField) }}
          {{ form_widget(emailField) }}
      </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

FormType:

```
        ->add('emailField', CollectionType::class,[
            'entry_type' => EmailFieldType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label'=> false],
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true
        ])
```

source:

```
   <div><label class="required">Email</label><div id="item_emailField"></div></div><input type="hidden" id="item__token" name="item[_token]" value="g52uiJ6OzlM3eXZY3Ifau71sbNpEihiaSTzz0dVYUW0" /></form>
```

What I want to achieve here is how to display CollectionType?

Comment: Can we see your formtype ?

Comment: I have added form @DylanKas

Comment: What is the name of your twig block containing your html ?

Comment: it's just {% block body %}

Comment: You should look into https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#fragment-naming-for-collections your block need to have specific name to work with your form

Comment: Where's the javascript part?

Comment: It could also help if you show the rendered source code.

Comment: ... and `EmailFieldType`

Comment: @ArleighHix I have added the source, I used exact same JS from documentation.